# Share windows authentication between sites when safari user access

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have 2 sites(let me call them siteA, siteB), Both of them are windows authentication. A iPad user can access siteA through a prompt dialog to input username and password.  but when the iPad user is redirected to siteB, the prompt dialog show again to let user input username and password. Is there any way to share the credential between the 2 sites?

Answer (score 0):

of course, if you want pass windows authentication without prompt dialog, you must set a authentication header in your http request.

So, if you are in Site A, then be redirected to site B, you must manipulate http request to site B, add authentication header to it, but HTTP headers are valid only for the current response. so you can not deal by this way.

Another alternative solution is using some extension on your browser, that pre-config user/password for each site has windows authentication.

Comment: thanks for your solution, Erics. but i cannot extend the browser for all users.

Comment: so, how about using a reverse proxy at site B?, check if refer http is site A, then add authentication header.